# does apropos have contradictory meanings?

Tags: meaning, contractions, irony

Definitions:
1) with reference to; concerning.
2) very appropriate to a particular situation.
3) used to state a speaker's belief that someone's comments or acts are unrelated to any previous discussion or situation.

definition 2 and 3 seem to directly contradict eachother. am I right to assume that you can use the word apropos to describe something as highly relevant AND irrelevant?

Source: [The Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22with%20reference%20to;%20concerning%22%20%22very%20appropriate%20to%20a%20particular%20situation%22%20%22comments%20or%20acts%20are%20unrelated%20to%20any%20previous%20discussion%20%22&source=bl&ots=d1VViSh8NU&sig=Hh-OtTdZZIn-C0gF3a0pPK6jshA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix59y4w7jKAhWGOBoKHbmmBYwQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22with%20reference%20to%3B%20concerning%22%20%22very%20appropriate%20to%20a%20particular%20situation%22%20%22comments%20or%20acts%20are%20unrelated%20to%20any%20previous%20discussion%20%22&f=false)

Comment: Your definition #3 relates to what's probably the most common collocation for the term: ***apropos of nothing***. I've never heard it used in that sense *without* those extra two words, but either you've mistranscribed the definition or that's what it's implying.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has mistranscribed/misunderstood a definition which makes it clear the third meaning relates to ***apropos of nothing***

Comment: @FumbleFingers google "apropos"

Comment: Obviously I just did that. It took a bit of extra Google-Fu to find the exact text you'd [mis-]cited above, but I got there in the end.

Answer (score 3):

***[Apropos](http://grammarist.com/usage/apropos/)*** is sometime erroneously used to mean "appropriate". The following extract may help:

> - The loanword apropos comes from the French phrase à propos de, meaning with respect to. In English, apropos is conventionally used as a preposition meaning with regard to, and it’s also an adjective for pertinent or to the point.
> - ***Apropos is often misused in place of appropriate***. This sense of apropos has nothing to do with the original French phrase or the word’s conventional meaning. In such cases, appropriate is a perfectly good replacement. Still, this use of apropos is common that we might simply have to accept that the word has changed.

Examples

- Apropos may be used alone or followed by of or to,

for example:

> - So Veronique de Rugy has responded to Nate Silver apropos the matter I discussed yesterday. [Guardian]
> - Apropos of nothing, we would like to take a moment to remind all period action films that horses do not explode like that. [Geek-o-System]

Apropos is sometimes questionably used as a synonym for appropriate—for example:

> - Bedford-Stuy Projects Probably Not Most Apropos Place for Prison-Themed Playground [Village Voice]
> - With April being Earth Month, it is apropos to take a look at what the transportation world holds beyond the current range of hybrids. [Calgary Herald]

(The Grammarist)